# How to disable mysql strict mode in kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, containers

I wanted to create a MySQL container in Kubernetes with default disabled strict mode. I know the way of how to disable strict mode in docker. I tried to use the same way in Kubernetes, but it shows an errors log.

docker

```sh
docker container run -t -d --name hello-wordl mysql --sql-mode=""
```

kubernetes

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-db
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-db
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-db
        image: mariadb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: ["--sql-mode=\"\""]
```

error:

> 2021-10-29 08:20:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.2.40+maria~bionic started.
> 2021-10-29 08:20:57+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
> command was: mysqld --sql-mode="" --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.i8yL5kgKoq
> 2021-10-29  8:20:57 140254859638464 [ERROR] mysqld: Error while setting value '""' to 'sql_mode'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error you're getting, it is reading the double quotes as value to sql_mode. You should omit the escaped double-quotes.

```
args: ["--sql-mode="]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to use a `configmap` for this.
Configmap manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-config
  labels:
    app: mysql
data:
  my.cnf: |-
    [client]
    default-character-set=utf8mb4
    [mysql]
    default-character-set=utf8mb4
    [mysqld] 
    max_connections = 2000
    secure_file_priv=/var/lib/mysql
    sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Deployment Manifest : in Volume section

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
    - name: config
      mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      subPath: my.cnf

  volumes:
  - name: config      
    configMap:
    name: mysql-config
```

This will replace your default `my.conf` in MySQL container, if you need to set more variables, better to include them in the `configmap`
[For more detailed answer](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/kubernetes-deploy-mysql-8.0-database-single-node.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I like your idea how to add the configuration, it look clean. But my container need to run query in entrypoint, so this way may not work for my case.